# Knockout js template, filter first element of observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hi I'm trying to make the first element of my observableArray hidden, the following doesn't appear to be working, any ideas?

**data-bind="ifnot: $root.typedData[0]===$data"**
http://jsfiddle.net/Lx8jR/

```
<table border="1" style="width:90%">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: typedData()[0].name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: typedData()[0].type"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table data-bind="foreach: typedData()">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
        </td>
        <td>
            <table data-bind="foreach: typedData()">
                <tr data-bind="ifnot: $root.typedData[0]===$data">
                    <td data-bind="text: type">

                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $index">
                    </td>  
                </tr>
            </table>           
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>


var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.typedData = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]).indexed();
}
```

Comment: So that readers are aware, this really isn't the correct way to bind to an observable array (it's not actually binding to the observable, but instead to the internal array the observable would normally proxy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you missed a () on that line.

```
ifnot: $root.typedData[0]===$data
```

becomes

```
ifnot: $root.typedData()[0]===$data
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx8jR/1/

A simple mistake I've made a few dozen times.

If you get into the habit of using `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` this becomes less of an issue.  If you use that function on a non-observable, it still succeeds.

```
... ko.utils.unwrapObservable($root.typedData)[0]
```

And for reference, there's an [article on KnockMeOut](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html) which suggests a few other standards that help simplify our templates and bindings.

Comment: Brilliant! that worked! Thanks for that. That's the 2nd time I've missed the round brackets! I'll look into unwrapObservable you mentioned, cheers for the extra info!

Answer (score 1):

`typedData` is an observableArray, so in your comparison you would want to do (add ()):

`$root.typedData()[0] === $data`